# HBox inside GridPane in Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have to add HBox to GridPane. If I add HBox to GridPane in same class then the system display correctly. But when I try with two classes, only empty window display.I'm new to javafx..How can I do that please help me thanks.

```
public class IpCamMainWindow  extends Application{

    private static ArrayList<IpCamViewer> ipCameraList = new ArrayList<IpCamViewer>();
    private static ArrayList<String> urls= new ArrayList<String>();
    GridPane grid =null;

    private ImageView imgWebCamCapturedImage;
    private BufferedImage grabbedImage;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>();
    private Webcam webCam = null;
    private boolean stopCamera = false;
    IPview ipCamViewer=null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(10);
        grid.setVgap(10);
        grid.setPadding(new Insets(0, 10, 0, 10));      

        for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
            ipCamViewer = new IPview();     

            grid.add(ipCamViewer, i%2, i/2);
            System.out.println("column: " + i%2 + ", row: " + i/2);

        }

        Scene scene = new Scene(grid);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("IP Camera Solution");
        stage.show();       

    }   

}
```

-

```
public class IPview extends HBox {  

    private ImageView imgWebCamCapturedImage;
    private BufferedImage grabbedImage;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>();
    HBox hbox;

    public IPview(){

        HBox hbox=addHBox();

    }

    public HBox addHBox() {
        hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button buttonCurrent = new Button("Current");
        buttonCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);

        Button buttonProjected = new Button("Projected");
        buttonProjected.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonCurrent, buttonProjected);

        return hbox;
    }   

}
```

Comment: You need to decide if `IPView` *is a* `HBox` (inheritance: `public class IPView extends HBox`) or if `IPView` *has a* `HBox` (aggregation: `HBox hbox`). Right now you have both, and you add the buttons to the aggregated `HBox`, but you add the `IPView` itself (which contains no buttons) to the `GridPane`.

Comment: I need to use inheritance (public class IPView extends HBox) then want to add HBox to the Gridpane.

Comment: So don't create another `HBox` as a field in `IPView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `IPView` is a subclass of `HBox`, you need to add the buttons to the `IPView` instance, and not create another `HBox` as a member variable of it.

I.e.

```
public class IPview extends HBox {  

    private ImageView imgWebCamCapturedImage;
    private BufferedImage grabbedImage;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>();

    public IPview(){

        this.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        this.setSpacing(10);
        this.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button buttonCurrent = new Button("Current");
        buttonCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);

        Button buttonProjected = new Button("Projected");
        buttonProjected.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        this.getChildren().addAll(buttonCurrent, buttonProjected);

    }   

}
```

If you want the `HBox` to be a member variable, then you would not make `IPView` a subclass of `HBox`, and just provide access to the `HBox`:

```
public class IPview {  

    private ImageView imgWebCamCapturedImage;
    private BufferedImage grabbedImage;
    private ObjectProperty<Image> imageProperty = new SimpleObjectProperty<Image>();
    private HBox hbox;

    public IPview(){

        hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(10);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button buttonCurrent = new Button("Current");
        buttonCurrent.setPrefSize(100, 20);

        Button buttonProjected = new Button("Projected");
        buttonProjected.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonCurrent, buttonProjected);

    }   

    public Node getView() {
        return hbox ; 
    }

}
```

And then in your application class you would do

```
        ipCamViewer = new IPview();     
        grid.add(ipCamViewer.getView(), i%2, i/2);
```

In general, I prefer the second approach, but that is just a matter of personal preference.